# Post a Question in MetaSO Prompt Error

Tags: bug, status-declined, title, featured-tag

I am not sure the below mentioned details are bug or the way Stack Overflow works. I tried entering invisible characters in the title and I found few more things which I need to share with you guys.

[image]

First thing first:

1. Why after I enter 148 character in the title the error message still shows up?

   > Title cannot be longer than 150 characters.
2. If I entered invisible characters in the title, why cant the error message could be like this?

   > You have entered invalid characters in the title.

   Although space is not an invalid character but some invisible characters should be omitted rite?
3. Its acceptable if I enter invisible characters in the body of my message like below:

> ```
>  ‌‌       ‌‌                ‌‌        ‌‌     ‌‌ ‌‌       ‌‌       ‌‌                ‌‌        ‌‌     ‌‌ ‌‌       ‌‌       ‌‌
> ```
>
> ‌‌        ‌‌     ‌‌ ‌‌       ‌‌       ‌‌                ‌‌        ‌‌
>   ‌‌ ‌‌       ‌‌       ‌‌                ‌‌        ‌‌     ‌‌ ‌‌       ‌‌
>   ‌‌                ‌‌        ‌‌     ‌‌ ‌‌      ‌‌       ‌‌
>   ‌‌        ‌‌     ‌‌ ‌‌       ‌‌       ‌‌                ‌‌        ‌‌

Note: I am not here to post an invisible question. Just curious to know these things.
(Question everything?)

Comment: Is the byte length of it UTF8 encoded more than 150?

Comment: @ColeJohnson not sure about UTF8.. I just copied from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978720/invisible-characters-ascii/17979246#17979246

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invisible_Man

Comment: @AaronBertrand :) ®™

Comment: I'm also amazed *"don't bang me for this!"* has survived this long without an edit.

Comment: @AaronBertrand removed :) I think one one is hearing this question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that this is not really worth fixing.

Don't enter a bunch of invisible characters in the title... Problem solved!

(For that matter, don't add them to the body of posts either, even though the system technically allows you to do so.)

Comment: That's what I am saying say the same thing in Error POPUP :) is it a bad idea?

Comment: @TomPHP well, if someone is entering invisible characters, and especially if they are *only* entering invisible characters, they are clearly *trying* to break something. Do you think a popup is really going to dissuade them? This is kind of like putting a "don't steal me!" sticker on all of the chocolate bars.

Comment: @TomPHP It's just not worth doing. This is an edge case. As Aaron mentioned, nobody is going to do this while trying to make a real, meaningful post. I'm entirely okay with people doing weird things getting weird and obscure errors.

Comment: Every thing has to be considered when your in internet.. (When your in a forest your a prey or pride.!) but still i understand what you told.